# Pair of pants decomposition for non-orientable surfaces

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, surfaces

Pair of pants decomposition on orientable surfaces is a classic way to decompose orientable surface to simples surfaces.

Is there a way to decompose non-orientable surfaces into pair of pants?

Basically the question boils to whether we can split the punctured Klein bottle or the twice punctured projective plane (since we could write every non-orientable surface as orientable part connected sum with Klein bottle or projective plane. Also we are only interested with surfaces with negative Euler characteristic, since too simple cases obviously can't be decomposed).

I think the answer is yes, and that in punctured  Klein bottle there are two splitting, according to the generators of the fundamental group.

I think that in the twice punctured projective plane we could split along a curve that splits the boundaries:

[image: Splitting of the Projective plane]

My intuition on non-orientable surfaces is not so good, so might miss something. Do you think that this is legit splitting? Do you have sources of splitting of non-orientable surfaces?

Comment: You’re certainly right about the punctured  Klein bottle: it can be obtained from a pair of pants by gluing two boundary components together with the same orientation.

Comment: @HJRW, and what about cutting along the other curve? What happen if I cut along the other curve in the fundamental polygon?

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean by “the other curve”, but in general this kind of thing is an elementary exercise that you can solve explicitly by looking at the fundamental polygon and figuring out which surface you are left with after you cut it up.